# Long press gesture in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How to get this content size reduce animation with jetpack compose when long pressed and then get normal when released(like the card in Spotify Android App).

Here is a gif showing the animation.

[image: Spotify Card]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a [**`Transition`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#updateTransition) to manage the animations between the pressed and release states.

```
enum class ComponentState { Pressed, Released }

var toState by remember { mutableStateOf(ComponentState.Released) }
val transition: Transition<ComponentState> = updateTransition(targetState = toState, label = "")

// Defines a float animation to scale x,y
val scalex: Float by transition.animateFloat(
    transitionSpec = { spring(stiffness = 50f) }, label = ""
) { state ->
    if (state == ComponentState.Pressed) 0.90f else 1f
}
val scaley: Float by transition.animateFloat(
    transitionSpec = { spring(stiffness = 50f) }, label = ""
) { state ->
    if (state == ComponentState.Pressed) 0.90f else 1f
}
```

Then you can use the [**`PointerInputScope.detectTapGestures`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/gestures/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.PointerInputScope).detectTapGestures(kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction2,kotlin.Function1)) to detect the press gestures:

```
val modifier = Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
    detectTapGestures(
        onPress = {
            toState = ComponentState.Pressed
            tryAwaitRelease()
            toState = ComponentState.Released
        }
    )
}
```

Finally apply the animation to your Composable.
For example:

```
Box(
    modifier
        .width((100 * scalex).dp)
        .height((100 * scaley).dp),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {

    Image(
        //...
        modifier = Modifier.graphicsLayer{
            scaleX = scalex;
            scaleY = scaley
        })
}
```

[image]